# Reset AutoComplete in React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, formik

I need to reset the `state_id` when I select the `city_id` Autocomplete.
How do I reset the `state_id`? It doesn't clear out.

Pls check codesandbox here

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-brook-33t6t?file=/src/index.js)

**CODE**

```
      <Autocomplete
        values={values.city_id}
        options={cities ? cities : []}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        onChange={(e, value) => {
          setFieldValue("city_id", value ? value : "");
          setFieldValue("state_id", "");
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            name="city_id"
            fullWidth
            label="City"
            variant="outlined"
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            helperText={touched.city_id && errors.city_id}
            error={touched.city_id && Boolean(errors.city_id)}
            {...params}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo is the reason it's not working as expected. Instead of `values={values.state_id}` you should write `value={values.state_id}` as the prop for the Autocomplete.

BTW, for these kinds of things ("do something in fieldA if fieldB changed") we built a component based on https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/1633#issuecomment-520121543 in my project. This is close to the API of https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik-effect, but still it may be worth implementing it yourself because jaredpalmer/formik-effect has not been committed to in the last 3 years.

Comment: Thanks a lot. will check it out